# Is the restriction $f$ of $F\in H^{-1}(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$ to $C_c^\infty(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$ a distribution?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$ denote the inner product on $L^2(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$
- $\mathcal D:=C_c^\infty(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$ and $$H:=\overline{\mathcal D}^{\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_H}$$ with $$\langle\phi,\psi\rangle_H:=\langle\phi,\psi\rangle+\sum_{i=1}^d\langle\nabla\phi_i,\nabla\psi_i\rangle\;\;\;\text{for }\phi,\psi\in\mathcal D$$
- $F\in H'$ and $f:=\left.F\right|_{\mathcal D}$

Can we prove the following claim? If so, *how*?

> Let $K\subseteq\Omega$ be compact and $\phi\in\mathcal D$ with $\operatorname{supp}\phi\subseteq K$ $\Rightarrow$ $\exists c\ge 0,k\in\mathbb N_0$ with $$\left|f(\phi)\right|\le c\sum_{\left|\alpha\right|\le k}\sup_K\left|\partial^\alpha\phi\right|\;.\tag 1$$

<s>By the [bounded linear transformation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension#Theorem), $F$ is *the* continuous linear extension of $f$ and hence $$\left\|F\right\|_{H'}=\left\|f\right\|_{\mathcal D'}\;.\tag 2$$ I'm new to distribution theory, but I could imagine that $\left\|f\right\|_{\mathcal D'}<\infty$ iff $(1)$ is satisfied.</s>

**EDIT**:
I was too hasty. $\mathcal D$ (equipped with the usual locally convex topology) is not a normed space and hence the mentioned theorem cannot be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me handle the case $d = 1$ for simplicity of notation. Since $H$ is a Hilbert space, $F$ is represented by an element $g \in H$. Thus, for all $\phi \in \mathcal{D} \subset H$ with $\operatorname{supp} \phi = K$ we have

$$ |F(\phi)| = \left| \left<\phi, g \right>_H \right| \leq ||g||_H ||\phi||_H = ||g||_H \left( \int_{\Omega} \phi \cdot \phi + \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \phi \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq ||g||_H \left( \int_{K} ||\phi||_{\infty,K}^2 + ||\nabla \phi||_{\infty,K}^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq ||g||_H \cdot \mu(K)^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \max (||\phi||_{\infty,K}, ||\nabla \phi||_{\infty,K})  $$

and so $f = F|_{\mathcal{D}}$ is a distribution of order (at most) o

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You've proved the claim without using $(2)$. Can you tell me if my conjecture "$\left\|f\right\|_{\mathcal D'}<\infty$ iff $(1)$" is correct?

Comment: What is $||f||_{\mathcal{D}'}$? The space of distributions $\mathcal{D}'$ with the usual topology placed on it is not a normed vector space.

Comment: $\mathcal D'$ can be defined as the topological dual space of $\mathcal D$, i.e. as the space of bounded, linear operators from $\mathcal D$ to $\mathbb R$. $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{\mathcal D'}$ denotes the operator norm.

Comment: Levap : you don't make a distinction between $\Omega$ bounded and not bounded ?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: The operator norm is relevant for operators between two normed spaces but the space $\mathcal{D}$ (again, with the relevant topology for the theory of distributions) is not normed...

Comment: @user1952009: I don't see why it is necessarily to make the distinction as $\varphi$ has compact support and so the integral is done on a bounded domain anyway.

Comment: @user1952009: Well, yeah, I need to change my last integral to be over $K$ instead of $\Omega$. Thanks, I've corrected the post.

Comment: my problem is that I don't see if we can say : as $n \to \infty$, $ \ \ \phi_n \to 0$ in $D(\Omega)$ topology $\implies$ $\phi_n \to 0$ in $H^k(\Omega)$ or not. Of course if $\Omega$ is bounded it is easy to show, but what if it is not ?

Comment: @user1952009: By definition of the topology on $\mathcal{D}$, if $\phi_n \rightarrow 0$ then there exists a compact $K \subset \Omega$ with $\operatorname{supp} \phi_n \subseteq K$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then we can choose an open bounded set $\Omega'$ such that $K \subset \Omega' \subseteq \Omega$ and then $||\phi_n||_{H^k(\Omega)} = ||\phi_n||_{H^k(\Omega')}$ so if you believe the result for bounded domains, it follows for general domains.

Comment: how do you know there is a bounded $K$ containing all the $supp\, \phi_n$ ?

Comment: @user1952009: By the definition of the topology on $\mathcal{D}$ - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics).

Comment: right I just understood, without the requirement that $supp\ \phi_n \subset K$ for some compact $K$, it becomes the Schwartz space. So the answer is obvious : $\phi_n \to \phi$ in test function topology $\implies \phi_n \to \phi$ in $H^k$ and $f \in H^{-k}$ is a distribution

Comment: @user1952009 At which stage of his proof did you think that it's imporant whether $\Omega$ is bounded or not? I don't see why your question about the convergence of your $(\phi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $\mathcal D(\Omega)$-topology is important.

Comment: @0xbadf00d :   He edited, on the second line at first he wrote $\int_\Omega$ instead of $\int_K$. And it is important in my "intuitive proof" :  that for any sequence $\phi_n \in C_c^\infty$, if $\phi_n \to \phi$ in the test function topology then $supp(\phi_n) \subset K$ some compact so that $\phi_n \to \phi$ in $H^k$, whence for any $f \in H^{-k}$ : $\ \ f(\phi_n) \to f(\phi)$ i.e. $f$ is a distribution

Comment: @levap Are you sure that your edit is correct? Since $\mathcal D$ is dense in $H$, the Hahn-Banach theorem should yield $$f=0\Leftrightarrow F=0\;.$$ **EDIT**: Didn't read your whole edit ;) Please note that $H$ **is defined to be** $H_0^1(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$.

Comment: @levap I thought about my second comment: Since $\mathcal D$ is a closed subspace of $H$, we can equip $\mathcal D$ with the restriction of $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_H$ and obtain a Hilbert space. Now, $f$ can be considered as a bounded, linear operator from $\mathcal D$ to $\mathbb R$. Moreover, we can apply the bounded linear transformation theorem and $F$ should be the unique continuous linear extension of $f$ with $\left\|F\right\|_{H'}=\left\|f\right\|_{\mathcal D'}$. With that in mind, how would you now respond to my second comment?

Comment: @levap In addition to my last question: Could you take a look at a [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848568/how-can-we-prove-left-left-f-right-mathfrak-d%ce%a9-0-leftrightarrow-exi)? Maybe you can help there too.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Sorry, I didn't notice that your $H$ is $H^1_0$. About your comment, $\mathcal{D}$ is not a closed subspace (since it is dense and not $H$) but you can indeed consider $\mathcal{D}$ with the induced norm from $H$ and then $f = F|_{\mathcal{D}}$ is continuous and $F$ is the unique extension of $f$ to $H$. However, this doesn't explain the relation of $f$ to distributions as the topology on $\mathcal{D}$ is not the standard topology one puts on the space in the theory of distributions.

Comment: @levap Yes, you're right. I'm a little bit confused about the relationship between $\mathcal D'$ and $H'$ and asked [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849115/relationship-between-c-c-infty-omega-mathbb-rd-and-h-01-omega-mathbb) for that. Maybe you can help me there too. Did you took a look at the [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848568/how-can-we-prove-left-left-f-right-mathfrak-d%ce%a9-0-leftrightarrow-exi) I've mentioned?