# Relationship between $C_c^\infty(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)'$ and $H_0^1(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)'$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$ denote the inner product on $L^2(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$
- $\mathcal D:=C_c^\infty(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$ and $$H:=\overline{\mathcal D}^{\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_H}\color{blue}{=H_0^1(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)}$$ with $$\langle\phi,\psi\rangle_H:=\langle\phi,\psi\rangle+\sum_{i=1}^d\langle\nabla\phi_i,\nabla\psi_i\rangle\;\;\;\text{for }\phi,\psi\in\mathcal D$$

> How are the [topological dual spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Continuous_dual_space) $\mathcal D'$ and $H'$ of $\mathcal D$ and $H$ related?

Let me share my thoughts and please correct me, if I'm wrong somewhere (and feel free to leave a comment, if everything is correct):

Let $f\in\mathcal D'$. If we equip $\mathcal D$ with the restriction $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{\mathcal D}$ of the norm induced by $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_H$, then $f$ is a bounded, linear operator from $(\mathcal D,\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{\mathcal D})$ to $\mathbb R$. Thus, since $\mathcal D$ is a dense subspace of $(H,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_H)$, we can apply the [bounded linear transform theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension#Theorem) and obtain the existence of a unique bounded, linear operator $F:(H,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_H)\to\mathbb R$ (i.e. $F\in H'$) with $$\left.F\right|_{\mathcal D}=f\tag 1$$ and $$\left\|F\right\|_{H'}=\left\|f\right\|_{\mathcal D'}\tag 2$$ where $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{\mathcal D'}$ denotes the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm#Introduction_and_definition) on $(\mathcal D,\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{\mathcal D})'$.

On the other hand, if $F\in H'$ and $$f:=\left.F\right|_{\mathcal D}\;,$$ then [we can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1848754/47771) that $f\in\mathcal D'$ where $\mathcal D'$ is equipped with the [usual topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Distributions). It's clear that $(2)$ is verified too.

> Is there any mistake in my argumentation? And what's meant if $\nabla\pi$ with $\pi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)'$ is claimed to be an element of $H$?

Comment: Since $D \subset H$, it follows that $H'\subset D'$.

Comment: @anonymus I don't think that it follows cause one **set** is a subset of the other. Could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Indeed, i went too fast. It is true for normed space but $D$ isn't. Its topology is quite complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I think your second argument is somewhat going into the wrong direction. You want to show that $H'\subset\mathcal{D}'$, so have to show two things:

1) Given $f\in H'$, you have $f\in\mathcal{D}'$, which follows since $\mathcal{D}$ is continuously embedded into $H$ (that you still have to show).

2) If two functionals $f,g\in H'$ coincide on $\mathcal{D}$, then they are equal. This follows since $\mathcal{D}\subset H$ is a dense subspace. Note that this does not mean that every functional on $\mathcal{D}$ has an extension to $H$. It only means if there is an extension, then it has to be unique, i.e., there is **at most one** extension.

Comment: (2) is a consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem. With "$f\in H'\Rightarrow f\in\mathcal D'$" in (1) you mean "$f\in H'\Rightarrow\left.f\right|_{\mathcal D}\in\mathcal D'$", right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: No, I don't think that (2) follows from the Hahn-Banach theorem since this does not give you uniqueness. Yes, (1) means $f\in H'\Rightarrow f|_D\in D'$. If you look at $f$ as a mapping from $H$ to $\mathbb{C}$, (1) reduces to the question of whether the embedding $D\to H$ is continuous, since then you can look at the composition $D\to H \to\mathbb{C}$, where the mapping $D\to H$ is the embedding and $H\to\mathbb{C}$ is $f$.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to do equip $ \mathcal{D}$ with the restriction $ \|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{D}}$ of the norm induced by $⟨⋅,⋅⟩_H$, because if you change the norm on $ \mathcal{D}$ you change $ \mathcal{D}' $.

For example condider $ C^{\infty}_{c}$ with the $ L^2 $ norm then the dual is $ L^2$.

Comment: I only equip $\mathcal D$ with $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{\mathcal D}$ in the first part. That should be no problem.

Comment: So how do you prove that $f$ is bounded in norm induced by $ \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_H $ to apply the theorem? For example consider the second derivative of $ \delta_0 $, then try to prove that is bounded in the $ H $ norm. (here is the mistake)

Comment: You should prove that for every $ \varphi \in \mathcal{D} $ you have $ \varphi''(0) \leq C\|\varphi\|_H $ with $ C $ independent of $ \varphi $.

Comment: Why should I prove that? You're right that I made a mistake in my reasoning. Is there anything else we can prove for the first part? Do you agree to the second part of my question?

Comment: You want to extend $ f $ to all $ H $ so $ f $ must to be a linear and continuous  (bounded) in $  H $ norm, which means that $ \|f(\varphi)\|_{H} \leq \| \varphi\|_{H} $. Note the norm are $ H $ norm.

Comment: Could you please explain why this extension is possible?

Comment: Hanh Banach....(Theorem)

Comment: Could you please give an answer. I'm written the question with the Hahn-Banach theorem in mind.

Comment: Let $ V \subset W $ normed spaces with the same norm. If you have a bounded linear map $ f: V \to \mathbb{R}$ you can extended to a linear map in all the space without increasing the norm of map. ok?

Comment: In the [formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Formulation) of the Hahn-Banach theorem, how do I need to choose $p$? It seems like we need to choose $p=\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_H$, but we don't have the inequality $f(\phi)\le \left\|\phi\right\|_H$ do we?

Comment: By the way: I still don't know why I should prove $\varphi''(0)\le C\left\|\varphi\right\|_H$. Please note that $0$ might be not in $\Omega$.

Comment: Actually you do not need to choose $ p = \|\cdot\|_H $. So if you are able to proof that $ f(\psi) \leq C\|\psi\|_{H} $ then you take $ p = C\|\cdot\|_{H}$ and apply Hanh Banach. But the fact that $ f(\psi) \leq C\|\psi\|_{H} $ (1) for all $ \psi $ is not true: for instance let $ x_0 \in \Omega $ and consider $ f $ equal the second derivative of $\delta_{x_0} $ then (1) is equivalent to prove that $ \psi''(x_0)\leq C\|\psi\|_{H}$ (which is not true).

Comment: It seems like I completely misunderstood you. So, you're trying to say to me that we cannot prove that there is some $F\in H'$ with $\left.F\right|_{\mathcal D}=f$, right?

Comment: If $ F \in H' $ then $ F|_{\mathcal{D}} = f \in \mathcal{D}' $.

Comment: But if $ f \in \mathcal{D}' $ then $ f \notin H'$ in general. All the other people that answer are saying the same thing.